# How can I play on two Xbox 360s with wireless controllers simultaneously?

Tags: technical-issues, xbox-360, controllers

We have 2 Xbox 360 consoles in our house. Neither are connected live. For some reason my son and my husband cannot play at the same time. They have wireless controllers and when the controllers seem to try to connect to either one or the other. Is there any way for them to be able to play at the same time?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if you have tried this yet, although you could press the sync button on the controller (right by the left bumper.) and then press the sync button on the 360. (It should have the same symbol as the one on the controller.)

Answer (score 0):

I would try connecting one up and then changing the settings to stop other controllers from being added and the attempt to connect the second one. Also maker sure that only the one you want to connect is in (if only one of them wants to play)

Answer (score 0):

I am sure this issue is caused by controllers paired with both consoles in your home. Please, check it and if need be, unpair the `incorrect` controller from one console and do the same thing with another. After that, please verify that the first controller is paired with X360 that you want to be paired with, and check the same with the second controller.

After that, you should not have any troubles like these you described in your question.